# Apple Cinema Display 30” black screen

Tags: display, cinema-display

I recently found a really nice-looking 30” Cinema Display in the trash at work, and I want to see if this thing is salvageable.

When connected to my Macbook Pro, the LED lights up and the computer detects the screen. I can see that the backlight on the monitor lights up when I hit the power button, and turns off when I hit it again. The USB ports are also working properly. But there is no image being displayed on screen.

Which components can I attribute this fault to, and is it irredeemable?